# Should JSON-encoded floats from the database be enclosed in quotes?

Tags: php, json, pdo

I have the following code:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM NODEGEOLOCATION WHERE NODEID = $i");
$stmt->execute();
$path[] = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

and I use json_encode to convert this to a JSON format. However, I am getting the following JSON:

```
[{"route":[{"LATITUDE":"32.224519","LONGITUDE":"-110.947325"},{"LATITUDE":"32.227820","LONGITUDE":"-110.947293"},{"LATITUDE":"32.227843","LONGITUDE":"-110.943865"},{"LATITUDE":"32.230618","LONGITUDE":"-110.943919"},{"LATITUDE":"32.231755","LONGITUDE":"-110.943927"},{"LATITUDE":"32.233836","LONGITUDE":"-110.943963"},{"LATITUDE":"32.233850","LONGITUDE":"-110.946061"},{"LATITUDE":"32.236035","LONGITUDE":"-110.946061"},{"LATITUDE":"32.235993","LONGITUDE":"-110.948083"},{"LATITUDE":"32.235977","LONGITUDE":"-110.952433"}]
```

I don't want the value of LATITUDE and LONGITUDE to be enclosed in quotes. Is this even possible?

Comment: Why are you using prepared statements if you are just injecting the PHP variable in using string concatenation? You should replace the `$i` with `?` and `execute()` with `execute(array($x))`. That way things will be properly escaped.

Comment: Can you explain why this is a problem?

Comment: This is *probably* a JSON question, not a PDO question -- retagged, retitled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like PDO **always** returns database results as strings, even when they are numbers or floats.

**PHP's JSON encoder doesn't perform any variety of type sniffing**: if the value is held in a PHP string, it gets put in quotes, even if it could be represented as an integer or float.

You can deal with this in two ways.

1. Expressly cast the value to a float before using `json_encode`.
2. Alter the consumer of the JSON to cast the value to a float before working with it.

---

Here's an example of automatic casting based on `getColumnMeta`.  First let's create a dummy database and insert some data.

```
php > $pdo = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
php > $pdo->exec('create table foo(a integer, b float, c text)');
php > $sh = $pdo->prepare('insert into foo(a, b, c) values(?, ?, ?)');
php > $sh->execute(array(1, 2.2, 'Three'));
php > $sh->execute(array(4, 5.55, 'Six'));
php > $sh->execute(array(7, 88.888, 'Nine'));
```

Now we'll prove that the data is there, for our demo:

```
php > $sh = $pdo->prepare('select * from foo where a = 4');
php > $sh->execute();
php > $row = $sh->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
php > var_dump($row);
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(1) "4"
  ["b"]=>
  string(4) "5.55"
  ["c"]=>
  string(3) "Six"
}
```

Let's see what PDO will tell us about the first column.

```
php > print_r($sh->getColumnMeta(0));
Array
(
    [native_type] => integer
    [sqlite:decl_type] => integer
    [flags] => Array
        (
        )

    [name] => a
    [len] => 4294967295
    [precision] => 0
    [pdo_type] => 2
)
```

Beautiful.  I did this for columns 1 and 2 as well, which returned "double" and "string" respectively.  Now let's build a map of column name to type:

```
php > $cols = count($row);
php > $col_types = array(); 
php > while($cols-- > 0) { 
          $col_info = $sh->getColumnMeta($cols);
          $col_types[ $col_info['name'] ] = $col_info['native_type']; 
      }
php > print_r($col_types);
Array
(
    [c] => string
    [b] => double
    [a] => integer
)
```

Yeah, it's in reverse, doesn't matter!  Now let's convert our row.

```
php > foreach($row as $k => $v) {
          if($col_types[$k] == 'double')
              $row[$k] = (float)$v;
          if($col_types[$k] == 'integer')
              $row[$k] = (int)$v;
      }
php > var_dump($row);
array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  int(4)
  ["b"]=>
  float(5.55)
  ["c"]=>
  string(3) "Six"
}
php > echo json_encode($row);
{"a":4,"b":5.55,"c":"Six"}
```

Tada!  You're probably going to want to wrap this in a convenience method, it's a bit hairy to do every single time by hand.  I could also have used [columnCount](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.columncount.php) to get the number of columns in the result set rather than counting `$row`.

---

Overkill much?  Here's an *untested* example that targets the specific column names and builds the array of hashes by hand in the process.

```
$results = array();
$convert_columns = array( 'b' );
$sh = $pdo->prepare('select * from foo where a = 1');
$sh->execute();
while($row = $sh->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    foreach($convert_columns as $colname)
        $row[$colname] = (float)$row[$colname];
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: Option 3 - `preg_replace` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#98987

Comment: how can you cast it to a float say in my example above? do a loop on the column latitude and cast it one by one?

Comment: @Phil: Sneaky!  Yeah, that'd work fine.  You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @EquinoX, if you wanted to do it "the right way", you'd call [`getColumnMeta`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) on the statement handle for each column, then loop through the result set and perform the required casting based on the information you gathered.  Because that is an *enormous* pain in the ass and Phil's link to the `preg_replace` hack should work perfectly fine for you, I'd just recommend doing that instead.

Comment: @Charles It's not my answer though and I like your first two suggestions better. It's also not going to play nice with a large result set

Comment: I can't use preg_replace as I am using a framework and I don't know where they put the json_encode in... I need a solution before I do json_encode, that's why I asked on how to do getColumnMeta

Comment: Oh *dear*.  Do you believe that the getColumnMeta trick will do the job for you?

Comment: well... then how would you do no. 1 on your answer above?

Comment: @EquinoX, I have dramatically expanded my answer with examples of `getColumnMeta` and a manual, precision targeted conversion.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on their type in the database I believe.

If they are varchars or string in the database they are treated as strings.

If they are `FLOAT`'s `DOUBLE`'s, they shouldn't have quotes.

Comment: FYI PDO returns everything as a string

Comment: It's actually decimal(8,6) in the table

Comment: My apologies. I could have sworn that it doesn't work like that. It may have been a different version. Not sure. I'll test when o get home.